# Concatenation of XMLs after merge is performed using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, concatenation

### file1.xml

```
<config>
 <state version="10">
  <root value="100" group="5">
     <leaf number = "2"/>
  </root>
  <action value="2" step="4">
     <get score = "5"/>
  </action>
 </state>
</config>
```

### file2.xml

```
<config>
 <state version="10">
  <root value="100" group="5">
     <leaf number = "6"/>
  </root>
  <parent>
      <child node="yes"/>
  </parent>
 </state>
</config>
```

### output.xml

```
<config>
 <state version="10">
  <root value="100" group="5">
     <leaf number = "2"/>
     <leaf number = "6"/>
  </root>
  <action value="2" step="4">
     <get score = "5"/>
  </action>
  <parent>
      <child node="yes"/>
  </parent>
 </state>
</config>
```

This is a follow up question to the one here: [Merge 2 XML files based on attribute values using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702554/merge-2-xml-files-based-on-attribute-values-using-xslt)

I have 2 different tags in each of the XML files (action tag in file1.xml and parent tag in file2.xml) and I need both of them to appear in the output file after the common tag () is traversed.

Please help me write an XSLT in making sure both these tags are reflected in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at JLRishie's fine answer, the following template to copy the matching **root** elements is given:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    <xsl:copy-of
      select="document('file2.xml')
          /config/state[@version = current()/../@version]
                 /root[@value = current()/@value and
                       @group = current()/@group]/*" />

  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

To extend this to get the non **root** elements from file2.xml, you could add a new template to match the **state** element in file1.xml, and then copy the non-root elements from file2.xml

```
<xsl:template match="state">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
     <xsl:copy-of
      select="document('file2.xml')
            /config/state[@version = current()/@version]/*[not(self::root)]" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="state">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="document('file2.xml')
              /config/state[@version = current()/@version]
                     /*[not(self::root)]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="document('file2.xml')
              /config/state[@version = current()/../@version]
                     /root[@value = current()/@value and
                           @group = current()/@group]/*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your two XML files, the following is output

```
<config>
   <state version="10">
      <root value="100" group="5">
         <leaf number="2"/>
         <leaf number="6"/>
      </root>
      <action value="2" step="4">
         <get score="5"/>
      </action>
      <parent>
         <child node="yes"/>
      </parent>
   </state>
</config>
```