# Merge 2 XML files (including node attributes) based on attribute values using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

Note: this is NOT a duplicate of 
[Merge 2 XML files based on attribute values using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702554/merge-2-xml-files-based-on-attribute-values-using-xslt/14702862)
but an extension to it. Given the following input files

file1.xml

```
<config>
 <state version="10">
  <root value="100" group="5">
     <leaf number = "2"/>
  </root>
  <root value="101" group="6" overrideAttr="oldval">
     <leaf number = "3"/>
  </root>
 </state>
</config>
```

file2.xml

```
<config>
 <state version="10">
  <root value="100" group="5">
     <leaf number = "6"/>
  </root>
  <root value="101" group="6" overrideAttr="newval" addtionalAttr="hello">
     <leaf number = "4"/>
  </root>
 </state>
</config>
```

I'd like to have this output.xml

```
<config>
 <state version="10">
  <root value="100" group="5">
     <leaf number = "2"/>
     <leaf number = "6"/>
  </root>
  <root value="101" group="6" overrideAttr="newval" addtionalAttr="hello">
     <leaf number = "3"/>
     <leaf number = "4"/>
  </root>
 </state>
</config>
```

Desired extensions are

- attributes (e.g. overrideAttr) on the "same node" (e.g. element root with value="101" and group="6") should be overwritten
- new attributes (e.g. addtionalAttr) should be added

Can this be achieved by xsl?

Comment: **1.** What defines "same" node? -- **2.** Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: >1.What defines "same" node?

see the "solution" of the above mentioned thread

>2. Please state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0

whatever javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory supports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the answer that you have linked to, there is an `xsl:apply-templates` that copies across the child elements from the second file.

```
  <xsl:apply-templates
    select="document('file2.xml')
          /config/state[@version = current()/../@version]
                 /root[@value = current()/@value and
                       @group = current()/@group]/*" />
```

All you need to do is add a similar line to copy across attributes

```
  <xsl:apply-templates
    select="document('file2.xml')
          /config/state[@version = current()/../@version]
                 /root[@value = current()/@value and
                       @group = current()/@group]/@*" />
```

Although this would need to done before the copying of any existing child nodes (as attributes must be added before child nodes).

Additionally, you might want to use a variable to avoid repeating the xpath expression.

Try this XSLT...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:variable name="file2root" select="document('file2.xml')
              /config/state[@version = current()/../@version]
                     /root[@value = current()/@value and
                           @group = current()/@group]" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$file2root/@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$file2root/*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this takes advantage of the fact that "*Adding an attribute to an element replaces any existing attribute of that element with the same expanded-name*". (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend that solution then you can do it as follows, change that template for the `root` elements (http://xsltransform.net/gWEamLR/1) to

```
      <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc2
              /config/state[@version = current()/../@version]
                     /root[@value = current()/@value and
                           @group = current()/@group]/@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="
        $doc2
              /config/state[@version = current()/../@version]
                     /root[@value = current()/@value and
                           @group = current()/@group]/*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

and make sure you define `<xsl:param name="doc2" select="document('file2.xml')"/>`.

There might be better ways using keys or grouping doing that merging, and of course in XSLT 3.0 we now have `xsl:merge`

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/" name="main">
        <config>
            <xsl:merge>
                <xsl:merge-source select="doc('file1.xml')/config/state">
                    <xsl:merge-key select="@version"/>
                </xsl:merge-source>
                <xsl:merge-source select="doc('file2.xml')/config/state">
                    <xsl:merge-key select="@version"/>
                </xsl:merge-source>
                <xsl:merge-action>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                        <xsl:merge>
                            <xsl:merge-source select="current-merge-group()[1]/root">
                                <xsl:merge-key select="@value"/>
                                <xsl:merge-key select="@group"/>
                            </xsl:merge-source>
                            <xsl:merge-source select="current-merge-group()[2]/root">
                                <xsl:merge-key select="@value"/>
                                <xsl:merge-key select="@group"/>
                            </xsl:merge-source>
                            <xsl:merge-action>
                                <xsl:copy>
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-merge-group()[2]/@*"/>
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-merge-group()/node()"/>
                                </xsl:copy>
                            </xsl:merge-action>
                        </xsl:merge>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:merge-action>
            </xsl:merge>
        </config>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```